# Keep firms observation if they are between a certain date range

Tags: r, group-by, subset

I have a question regarding subsetting in r. I have a large dataset and I only want to keep firms if they have observations for 2000 until 2019. So if a firm has for example observations between 2000 and 2005 the firm has to be deleted.

```r
fiscal_year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
fkey <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(fiscal_year, fkey)
```

My desired output is to only keep the 20 firm year observations of firm 2. I tried several commands in R so far:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(fkey) %>% 
  subset(fiscal_year==2000 & fiscal_year==2001 & fiscal_year==2002 & fiscal_year==2003 & fiscal_year==2004 & fiscal_year==2005 & fiscal_year==2006 & fiscal_year==2007 & fiscal_year==2008 & fiscal_year==2009 & fiscal_year==2010 & fiscal_year==2011 & fiscal_year==2012 & fiscal_year==2013 & fiscal_year==2014 & fiscal_year==2015 & fiscal_year==2016 & fiscal_year==2017 & fiscal_year==2018 & fiscal_year==2019)
```

But this command deletes all firms.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(fkey) %>%
  subset(fiscal_year>=2000 & fiscal_year<=2019)
```

But this command keeps all firms.

So, I don't know how to change the command that it works!

Hopefully everything is clear and if not, please comment!

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
firms <- unique(df$fkey)

for (i in 1:length(firms)){
  df_firm <- df[df$fkey == firms[i],]
  if (min(df_firm$fiscal_year) > 2000 | max(df_firm$fiscal_year) < 2019){
    df$fiscal_year[df$fkey == firms[i]] <- NA
  }
}

df <- df[complete.cases(df),] #remove years with NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` to keep the firms that has all the years from 2000 to 2019.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(fkey) %>%
  filter(all(2000:2019 %in% fiscal_year)) %>%
  ungroup -> result

result
#   fiscal_year  fkey
#         <dbl> <dbl>
# 1        2000     2
# 2        2001     2
# 3        2002     2
# 4        2003     2
# 5        2004     2
# 6        2005     2
# 7        2006     2
# 8        2007     2
# 9        2008     2
#10        2009     2
#11        2010     2
#12        2011     2
#13        2012     2
#14        2013     2
#15        2014     2
#16        2015     2
#17        2016     2
#18        2017     2
#19        2018     2
#20        2019     2
```